# Why does IIS Express Restart my App Pool in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, razor, restart

I have a fairly complex MVC Application which must initialize when the Application starts. I am trying to diagnose why the App pool is restarting after the first MVC page is rendered. To diagnose this issue, I put break points on Application_Start and Application_End. Applicaiton_Start is called as expected. At the end of the first returned HTML/Razor page from my application, Application_End is called. On the next page request, Application_Start get called again, and then seems to run as expected without restarting.

I thought this was caused by Razor compiling the views at runtime, which would then updating the BIN foldee.  I know that IIS and IIS Express restart the APP pool when the BIN folder is updated, so I assumed this MVC Razor compllation was causing the IIS process to restart the app pool. To mitigate this, I followed the instructions here: https://chrismckee.co.uk/asp-net-mvc-compiled-views/ to pre-compile my Razor views. I know that the vies are now pre-compiled, as this did locate several compile issues [compile errors] that would not have been found until runtime without these configuration changes resulting in the pre-complication of the Razor views.

So the question is this:

1) How Can I diagnose why the app pool is restarting?

2) Does anyone know why this happens in and MVC application running in IISExpress?

[... and obviously, how to prevent it from happening]

Thanks

jloper

Update #2:

I looked up Browser Link and figured out quickly that it not necessary and really not being used.  I turn off BrowserLink and sure enough, the exception goes away.  Now the Application_Start is called as expected, Application_End is called [and no exception has occurred (System.GetLastError() returns null].  Application_Exception is NEVER called.  Application_Start is called a second time.

All state of the application is reset when the Application_End is called.

Update #1:

As suggested, I added Application_Error and retrieved the last exception using Server.GetLastError().  Here is the exception that was returned:

```
The thread 0xc4c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/__browserLink/requestData/8cf754f80e264fd392f4a0fbffea67e4' was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Also, I added the same code to Application_End.  At the point that Application_End is being called, System.GetLastError() return nulls.

Comment: how about looking at `Application_Error` and looking at `Server.GetLastError()`? (it also wouldn't be a bad idea to add Elmah or some other logging mechanism to your site so you can have more insight)

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Razor compiling views.  That's a complete red herring.  Razor does not update anything in the bin folder, views are compiled and stored in the temporary asp.net folder, and this does not affect the app pool.  More than likely, your app is throwing an exception of some sort that isn't getting caught.

Comment: As suggested:  I added Application_Error and retrieved the exception using Server.GetLastError().  Here is the exception that was returned:

Answer (score 3):

I found a trick somewhere on the web (forget where) that you can use reflection to get the reason in the application_end event:

```
Sub Application_End(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim runtime As HttpRuntime = CType(GetType(HttpRuntime).InvokeMember("_theRuntime", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing), HttpRuntime)
        Dim shutDownMessage = CType(runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownMessage", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField, Nothing, runtime, Nothing), String)
        Dim shutDownStack = CType(runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownStack", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField, Nothing, runtime, Nothing), String)

       'Log reason
```

outside of adding IIS tracing, this was a code-specific way that I was able to extract the reason...

Comment: This code (converted to c#) was very useful to me, thanks. Eventually I found the source, on Scott Gu's blog, here it is: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Brian Main's answer worked perfectly, showing me the message that a file changed in the project folder, which caused a restart.

For those interested, here is the C# version.

```
var runtime = typeof (HttpRuntime).InvokeMember("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField, null, null, null);
var shutDownMessage = runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownMessage", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null);
var shutDownStack =  runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownStack",   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a bug in Visual Studio's "Browser Link" feature.  This was fixed in an update.  Apply the latest Update (Update 4) to Visual Studio 2013 and your problem should be fixed.